# How to function more a replace function to be more specific

Tags: python

I have this function that asks the user for a string and once it gets the string then it asks the user which letter they want to change and then ask them what to change those letters too. What I need it to do is ask the user for a string than me as a user choice only 8 letters that can be changed and I also pick what those letters can be changed to. The output is like this . String HELLO, What letters should be changes EO. print H3llO. I want E to change to 3, o to be 0, I to be 1, C to be [.

This what I have so far.

```
def replace():

    old,new = [],[]
    newString = ""

    string = input('new_uppercase')
    char = input("Change: ")
    toThis = input("Change " + char + " to this: ")

    for x in range(0,len(string)):
        old.append(string[x])

    for y in range(0,len(old)):
        if old[y] != char:
            new.append(old[y])
        else:
            new.append(toThis)

    for z in range(0,len(new)):
        newString+=new[z]
        print(newString)

replace()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well if you have constant set of values with which you are replacing each character. Otherwise, you can create replacement map at runtime after getting input from user.

```
replacements = {
    'E': '3',
    'O': '0',
    'C': '['
}

def replace():
    old,new = [],[]
    newString = ""
    string = input('new_uppercase')
    char = input("Change: ")
    for ch in char:
        if replacements.get(ch):
            string = string.replace(ch, replacements.get(ch))
    print(string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    replace()
```

Comment: new_uppercase HELLO
Change: EO
Change EO to this:
H3LL0